# Page number resets on Table of Contents

Tags: table-of-contents, page-numbering

I am using Roman page numbering for the abstract / ToC / list of figures etc before the main body of my thesis. The number seems to reset at the table of contents page (i.e. back to the roman numeral 'i', even if the previous page is numbered 'iv'). Here's my code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}

\begin{document}

\title{This is the Title}
\author{Author}
\maketitle

\pagenumbering{roman}

\begin{abstract} 
\thispagestyle{plain}
Abstract goes here... \newpage
page 2
\end{abstract}

\tableofcontents
\thispagestyle{plain}

\clearpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\chapter{Chapter 1}
\section{Unhelpful content 1}
\section{Unhelpful content 2}

\end{document}
```

I have tried patching the `\tableofcontents` command using the following code in the preamble

```
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\tableofcontents}{\pagenumbering{arabic}}{}{}{}
\makeatother
```

but to no avail. Can anyone tell me how I can stop the page number resetting? Thanks!

Comment: The abstract environment uses the titlepage environment which resets the page number to zero. I would suggest to use a better class, e.g. `scrreprt`.

Comment: Ah, thanks - it never occurred to me that it could be the abstract environment causing the issue! Switching to koma-script at this late stage is going to be too problematic for me so I'm going to look to redefine the environment...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are depending on `report` and want to use the `abstract` environment, you will have to redefine that environment.

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{abstract}{%
    \if@twocolumn
    \section*{\abstractname}%
    \else
    \small
    \begin{center}%
        {\bfseries \abstractname\vspace{-.5em}\vspace{\z@}}%
    \end{center}%
    \quotation
    \fi}
{\if@twocolumn\else\endquotation\fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}    
    \title{This is the Title}
    \author{Author}
    \maketitle  
    \pagenumbering{roman}   
    \begin{abstract} 
        \thispagestyle{plain}
        Abstract goes here... \newpage
        page 2
    \end{abstract}  
    \tableofcontents
    \clearpage
    \pagenumbering{arabic}  
    \chapter{Chapter 1}
    \section{Unhelpful content 1}
    \section{Unhelpful content 2}   
\end{document}
```

This will set the abstract to the top of the second page. Maybe it looks nicer to have the abstract on the first page. Use `\documentclass[notitlepage]{report}` then.

Comment: Thanks very much. This is the line I think I will go down. I'm not very familiar with redefining environments - is there any way I can adapt your code above so the abstract is centred vertically?

Comment: @TomOffer Sorry, I am not good in redefing environments, either. Please ask a new question regarding this problem.